# Inserting an Array into Postgres Database from a Ruby File

Tags: ruby, postgresql, error-handling

I'm trying to transfer all the information from my Ruby file into a Postgres database. I am able to transfer the information when I do not have an array column, so I am assuming the error message I am getting is because of the array column I am trying to add. The error message I am getting is:

```
in `exec_prepared': ERROR:  missing dimension value (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation)
```

Here is the code I used to connect my Ruby file to my Postgres database:

```
require 'pg'

class Postgres
  # Create the connection instance. Scraping is the name of the database I am adding this information to
  def connect
    @conn = PG.connect(:dbname => 'scraping')
  end

  # Create our venue table
  def createVenueTable
    @conn.exec("CREATE TABLE venues (venue_number varchar(15) UNIQUE,...,img_array varchar[]);")
  end

  ...

  def prepareInsertVenueStatement
    @conn.prepare("insert_venue", "insert into venues(venue_number,...,img_array) values ($1,...,$24)")
  end

  # Add a venue with the prepared statement.
  def addVenue(venue_number,...,img_array)
    @conn.exec_prepared("insert_venue", [venue_number,...,img_array])
  end
end
```

When I check my Postgres database, the img_array column is made, however, I am unable to populate it. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: you could serialize the `Array` to make it a YAML `String` and then deserialize it when you retrieve it back out of the database. This is how [rails](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) deals with this scenario at least.

Comment: @engineersmnky I can't really do that because I am only using a ruby file

Comment: Sure you can it's fairly simple. I will write up a brief answer

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using serialization to handle this so that you are actually just writing a string rather than an actual array.

```
require 'pg'
require 'yaml'

class Postgres
  # Create the connection instance. Scraping is the name of the database I am adding this information to
  def connect
    @conn = PG.connect(:dbname => 'scraping')
  end

  # Create our venue table
  def createVenueTable
    #changed img_array to a varchar(8000) for storing serialized Array
    @conn.exec("CREATE TABLE venues (venue_number varchar(15) UNIQUE,...,img_array varchar(8000));")
  end

  ...

  def prepareInsertVenueStatement
    @conn.prepare("insert_venue", "insert into venues(venue_number,...,img_array) values ($1,...,$24)")
  end

  # Add a venue with the prepared statement.
  def addVenue(venue_number,...,img_array)
    @conn.exec_prepared("insert_venue", [venue_number,...,serialized(img_array)])
  end
  #serialize the Object
  def serialized(obj)
     YAML.dump(obj)
  end
  #deserialize the Object
  def deserialized(obj)
     YAML.load(obj)
  end
end
```

Abstracted Usage Example just to show serialization

```
a = [1,2,4,5]
serialized = YAML.dump(a)
#=> "---\n- 1\n- 2\n- 3\n- 4\n- 5\n"
YAML.load(serialized)
#=> [1,2,3,4,5]
#Also works on Hash Objects
h = {name: "Image", type: "jpeg", data:[1,2,3,4,5]}
serial = YAML.dump(h)
#=> "---\n:name: Image\n:type: jpeg\n:data:\n- 1\n- 2\n- 3\n- 4\n- 5\n"
YAML.load(serial)
#=> {:name=>"Image", :type=>"jpeg", :data=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Hope this helps you out with handling this issue.

If you need to store more than 8000 characters you can switch to varchar(MAX) or text column definitions. I would recommend varchar(MAX) because the data will be stored as a standard varchar until it exceeds 8000 character at which point the db basically converts it to a text column under the hood.

Comment: Downvoting because storing a YAML serialized Array does not let you use any of Postgres's array functions, and is in no way equivalent to what the author wanted to do.

Comment: @TheSuper I can accept that although you seem to be speaking for the OP here. That being said the postgres_ext gem could be of some help or just a basic insert statement using `ARRAY[]`